# Django | Redirect View after "liking" without scrolling

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-views

I'm making a simple blog app.  I have added the ability to "like" a post on your feed.  However, the only way I can figure out closing a view is by returning some form of redirect.  The problem is, if the post you're "liking" is halfway down the page, I don't want it to reset the zoom to the top of the page again.  Is there a way simply to redirect to the same page without affecting zoom?

Here's my post model:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    content = models.TextField()
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="author")
    likes = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name="likes", blank=True)

    def like(self, post):
        self.likes.add(post)

    def unlike(self, post):
        self.likes.remove(post)
```

I have the following setup in Views:

```
@login_required
def like(request, pk):
    post = Post.objects.get(id=pk)
    Post.like(post, request.user)
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('Home'))


@login_required
def unlike(request, pk):
    post = Post.objects.get(id=pk)
    Post.unlike(post, request.user)
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('Home'))
```

Here's how I'm calling the Views from my URLs:

```
path('like/<int:pk>', views.like, name='Like'),
path('unlike/<int:pk>', views.unlike, name='Unlike'),
```

I'm using a form on my template to trigger the URL:

```
{% if user in post.likes.all %}
<form action="{% url 'Unlike' post.pk %}" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <button type="submit" value="{{ post.id }}" class="unlike">UNLIKE</button>
</form>
{% else %}
<form action="{% url 'Like' post.pk %}" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <button type="submit" value="{{ post.id }}" class="like">LIKE</button>
</form>
{% endif %}
```

Is there something I can change?  I'm assuming there's something I'll need to change or add under "return" in my view functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this would be adding an anchor tag to each like button that uses the post ID, then when redirecting to the post from your view, include #pk at the end of the post URL to direct to that ID anchor down the page.

Comment: This worked! I'd still like to find a way to do it without any redirecting if I can, but thank you for helping me out with this!